# How can I update a recurring event with some exemptions but still maintaining the "Confirmed" status for the exempted instances?

Tags: google-calendar-api

If I update a recurring instances with EXDATES populated, the instances provided under it got "Cancelled". How can I prevent that?

Also, is it possible to update an event using "privateExtendedProperty" fields?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include [example] describe any issues with your current solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.